# App Didn't Build - And i Don't started to code yet

Tags: react-native, gradle, mobile, module

I'm Igor.

I am Studying ReactNative at the moment, and trying to make a simple app  - it is a calculator that shows the result in an alert box and on a second page - as part of my studies. But, when I added code to import the parts of some external packages, simply I get Gradle errors! The error starts saying "Unable to resolve module ," so I install the package that the error asks for, and I get the same error, with another package name ("Unable to resolve module < another package name>",) I install the other package and get this type of error again and again until I rebuild the app (npx react-native run-android) an I get some Gradle error (the error says "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
60 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 58 up-to-date")

I tried to start a completely new project. No errors. I opened App.js and changed the status bar color to test. No errors. Then, I inserted some code to use some package That I installed before

```js
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

and the SAME error simply started. The ReactNative asked for the following packages in this exact order:

- react-native-safe-area-content
- react-native-gesture-handler

  - @react-native-comunity/masked-view
  - react-native-screens

Then the error appeared. I neither started to code! How can I do it?

EDIT: The external modules that I installed to use are:

-react-native-vector-icons 
-react-native-paper 
-@react-navigation/native
-@react-navigation/stack

Comment: Which error it is?

Comment: The terminal said: "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings 60 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 58 up-to-date" at the end of the error. I cannot build the app

Comment: I add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands in the terminal of your root directory of the project.

```
npm i jetifier --save
npx jetify
```